# X11 on server without forwarding

Tags: ubuntu, x11

I'm running a java application on my ubuntu server which refuses to open if it cannot open a window (the content of the windows is of no interest for me).
Since the server is not connected to any screen I don't want to have a full running x11 environment like openbox. Currently I'm forwarding this window over ssh to my pc but this way the program closes whenever I'm rebooting the pc.
What could be a good solution for this? (I'll never need to see the content of the window)

Comment: Is there an option on the command line to disable this requirement?

Comment: Related (maybe not exact duplicate because there might be something specific to Java): [How can I run Firefox on Linux headlessly (i.e. without requiring libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9107)

Answer (score 6):

[Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) is an X server intended for situations like yours.

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu's xvfb package includes a script, `xvfb-run`, which will automatically launch an Xvfb instance and run your program with `$DISPLAY` pointing to that instance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a headless jre, e.g. the package 
**default-jre-headless**.