# Run app on X11 on server without forwarding

Tags: x11, xforwarding

### The problem

I am using an application that is computationally intensive and **requires** X11 to run. I want to run it on a remote server (that is obviously running X11).

**I don't need to forward X11, I just need it to run on the server.**

### More details

If I run the application from the server (i.e. I use the keyboard that is physically connected to the machine), then everything works fine. My problem is that I want to start this application remotely (from an SSH connection) because I cannot always access the server physically.

I am not completely sure how it works, but when I run the following command **from the machine** (i.e. using its keyboard):

```
$ xhost +
```

then I can run my app (`$ DISPLAY=:0 ./run-my-app`) without problem from SSH. Now, I cannot run `xhost +` from SSH, and anyway it sounds like a bad idea in terms of security.

If I don't run `xhost +`, I get the following output:

> No protocol specified
>
> xauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display ":0".

In conclusion, it looks like there is some security feature (access control) that prevents me from running the app on X11 remotely. But the point is that I don't want to have more than what happens when I start the app from the server (with the keyboard connected to the physical machine); I just want to start/stop it remotely, without any forwarding.

Is there a way to do that?

### Similar questions

It looks similar to [X11 on server without forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48625/x11-on-server-without-forwarding) and [How can I run Firefox on Linux headlessly (i.e. without requiring libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9107/how-can-i-run-firefox-on-linux-headlessly-i-e-without-requiring-libgtk-x11-2-0), but in these situations they can use a virtual server like *Xvfb*, which does not work in my case. Moreover, I do have an X server running on the server, and I do need it.

Answer (score 0):

steal a copy of the enviroment of the running session

```
pid="`pgrep process_name\$ -U $USER`"
env `tr '\0' ' ' < "/proc/$pid/environ"` program_name
```

for a suitable value of `process_name`: something that you know is running in your X11 environment

Comment: The full command was not working for some reason, so I copied the output of `tr '\0' ' ' < /proc/$pid/environ` and ran `env "<the_output_from_cat>" <program_name>`, but I still get the same xauth error =(.

Comment: maybe try this instead `tr ' \t\0' '__ ' `  or try snooping on a different process,