# Binvox not working on a headless Linux server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11

I'm trying to run Binvox (http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~min/binvox/) via web server, on an Amazon EC2 server with Nvidia GRID K520 GPU and running Ubuntu 14.04. I'm using the `system(binvox, $ret)` function call in my PHP script. However, Binvox uses an X11 window to display its processing, and thus fails to run.

According to the documentation, the `-pb` option should make it work on a headless server, however, that did not work for me. I tried using `Xvfb` to run it but I get the following error:

> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":99". freeglut (./binvox): OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':99'

Note that applications like `firefox` and `xclock` work fine with `Xvfb`, but I get a similar error with `glxinfo`. I tried the suggestions/solutions given [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114918/xlib-extension-glx-missing-on-display-0) and [here on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67567/extension-glx-missing-on-display), but it did not work for me. I'm not sure where should I start looking to fix it.

Comment: Did you try its `-pb` option?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, yes I did; but it still did not work for want of a display. With Xvfb, I was able to run other applications like firefox and xclock, however while running binvox, I get the following error: `Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":99".
freeglut (./binvox): OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':99'`. I get a similar error with glxinfo, so it's probably some error in my setup; I am trying to find it and fix it first.

Comment: Please edit the question to say `Xvfb` doen not work for you - otherwisw it would be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is made possible by installing Xvfb (X virtual frame buffer `apt-get install xvfb`) and specifying the DISPLAY variable.

```
Xvfb :25 -screen 0 1900x1080x32 &
export DISPLAY=:25
binvox [WHATEVER OPTIONS AND SWITCHES YOU WANT TO PASS TO binvox] &
```

Hat tip to @Gilles' answer to this U&L Q&A titled: [How can I run Firefox on Linux headlessly (i.e. without requiring libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9118/24379).

Some more information is available here in this articled titled: [Running Selenium Headless](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2008/03/05/running-selenium-headless/).